# Why is that `ncal -CM` doesn't work but `ncal -MC` does?

Tags: shell, cal

I wanted to put a calendar in a file so I ran:

```
$ ncal -CMh > file.txt
```

But instead I received the following:

```
Usage: cal [general options] [-hjy] [[month] year]
       cal [general options] [-hj] [-m month] [year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
General options: [-NC31] [-A months] [-B months]
For debug the highlighting: [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

I was surprised because I was sure the command is correct. I thought perhaps, `getopts` options are not permutable like I thought so I tried reordering the options. However all permutations that didn't have `-C` before `-M` worked:

```
$ ncal -hC
$ ncal -Ch
$ ncal -hM
$ ncal -Mh
$ ncal -MCh
$ ncal -MhC
$ ncal -hMC
$ ...
```

My theory is that when `ncal` enters cal mode using `-C` it loses the `-M` option probably because `-M` didn't exist in original `cal`. I have no idea if this is correct or not.

Why does this happen?

This is on latest Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 3):

The usage message shows the valid options for `cal` and `ncal`:

> ```
> Usage: cal [general options] [-hjy] [[month] year]
>        cal [general options] [-hj] [-m month] [year]
>        ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
>        ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
> General options: [-NC31] [-A months] [-B months]
> ```

After a `-C` flag, you can only use general options or valid `cal` options,
*until an `-N` flag switches back to `ncal` mode*, after which you can use general options or valid `ncal` options. Until another `-C` flag switches back to `cal` mode, and so on.